# Read text file into Clipboard

Tags: c#

after along time of searching via google, I decided to poste my problem here.
First: I am total C# Noob. 
 I am using a Macro Recorder from Jitbit and I have no choice to use a different. The Problem is in the Macro Recorder, it is missing some essential things.
Like reading a text file into a variable and paste this variable via Clipboard :-(
However the good thing is, the tool support "some" type of native C# Code

If I open the C# Command I get this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

And the C# program has to follow also these rules:
=> This Code MUST contain a class named "Program" with a static method "Main"
I already used google and found code that should do the job but I get errors, I guess the
code doesn`t follow the above rules.
This is what I found and tried:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    // Read the file as one string.
    System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
     new System.IO.StreamReader("Counter.txt");
    string counter = myFile.ReadToEnd();

    myFile.Close();

    // Load string into clipboard
    Clipboard.SetDataObject( counter, true );
    }
}
```

I always get the error : "Line 15: The Name Clipboard is not existing in the context"?!?
I hope that someone can explain a noob (me) what is wrong and what is the correct code.
Thanks.

Comment: Write it this way instead: `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject( counter, true);`

Comment: Yes homework for me :D

Answer (score 3):

add reference to `System.Windows.Forms`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(File.ReadAllText("Counter.txt"), true);
    }
}
```

Note that  to Avoid the ThreadStateException you need to applying the STAThread attribute to your Main() function

Comment: You can just do `Clipboard.SetDataObject(File.ReadAllText("Counter.txt"), true);` - no need to mess around with `StreamReader`.